# Cloud Firestore: model membership invites

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-design, firebase-security, member

I'm writing an app based on Cloud Firestore using the Web Client SDK v9 (but this is a more generic issue with database architecture that is not necessarily related to this specific SDK).

I want to implement the following features:

- users can create groups
- users can invite other users to join their group by sending an invite code (the app creates an invite code that shall grant access to the related group)
- other users can use this invite code to join the group

This is how I want to model the handling of the invites / join group in the security rules:

- only users that are member of a group can read it
- only users that are member of a group can write it, except for:

  - users with an valid invite code can write themselves as a member into the group

Modeling this in Cloud Firestore seems to be impossible.

So far I have one collection `groups` and another collection `invites`. An invite has the invite code as `doc.id` and a field `groupId` that has the id of the group it shall grant access to.

There are two ways I found to model group memberships in general, but it seems that none of those ways allow to model the security rules as described above:

A) a group has a **sub-collection** `members`, to which an user with a valid invite code can add themselves. The writing can be modeled in the security rules as follows:

```bash
match /groups/{groupID} {
  function hasValidInvite() {
    return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/invites/$(request.resource.data.inviteCode));
  }

  match /members/{memberID} {
    allow write: if hasValidInvite();
  }
}
```

So writing of memberships works, but it seems to be impossible to query all memberships of an user, because collection queries can't do `where(documentId(), "==", getAuth().currentUser.uid)` on sub-collections (this seems to be some bug).

Because of this issue, the second approach is recommended:

B) a group has an **array field** `members`, to which the user id is being written. Reading this is super easy, I just have to check if the current `uid` is in the `members` array of a group. But I found no way to write security rules that allow someone to do nothing else than an `arrayUnion()` and only on the field `members` and only to the group they have an valid invite for.

So I have two very different approaches that each cover half of the solution but are incompatible.

Any ideas how I should approach this?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the two solutions can be combined with the help of a Cloud Function that listens to changes to documents in the `members` collection and writes the `id` of the newly created document to the `members` array in the respective `groups` document:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

let isWriteMembershipToGroupInitialized = false;

exports.writeMembershipToGroup = functions.firestore
    .document("/groups/{groupId}/members/{memberId}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const admin = require("firebase-admin");
      if (!isWriteMembershipToGroupInitialized) {
        admin.initializeApp();
        isWriteMembershipToGroupInitialized = true;
      }

      const docRef = admin.firestore().doc("groups/" + context.params.groupId);
      return docRef.update({
        members: admin.firestore
            .FieldValue
            .arrayUnion(context.params.memberId),
      }, {merge: true});
    });
```

Drawbacks:

- introduces new SDK (Firebase has a ton of different SDKs for different use cases and each of them acts slightly different)
- requires upgrade to paid plan (although there still is a free tier, you have to provide billing information)
- Cloud Functions might take a couple of seconds to spin up, so the change might not be visible to the user right away!